# Problem with NotEqualTo filters in SLD and CSS

Tags: geoserver, sld, css

I am having a bit of a problem with using a '<>' attribute filter in CSS for GeoServer.  I have parred my CSS down to the absolute minimum for a buildings layer as follows:

```
[aeroway <> 'terminal']{
  fill: #aa1111;
}
```

The auto-generated SLD is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>aeroway</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>terminal</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#aa1111</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:VendorOption name="ruleEvaluation">first</sld:VendorOption>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

According to the documentation both `<>` for CSS and `PropertyIsNotEqualTo` for SLD are perfectly valid.  The layer contains data and shows fine if I remove the filter, so the problem does not lie with the data.

Interestingly, PostGIS does not return data whose aeroway data is Null if you send it an SQL as follows:

```
select * from buildings where aeroway <> 'terminal'
```

In PostGIS, the above query returns only buildings whose aeroway attribute is both NOT NULL *and* NOT 'terminal'.  That was a surprise because I was expecting to get absolutely everything that did not have a value of 'terminal' (including the null values).  So, potentially the problem might lie with my expectations of PostGIS's approach to SQL.

Is this normal behaviour and can anybody suggest a work-around please (`aeroway = ''` does not work)?

Comment: I made a test with Spatialite and it gives the same result which makes me believe that skipping NULLs is correct and with SQL you should add `OR aeroway is NULL`.

Comment: There is a PropertyIsNull function you could use, I believe we tried to match what SQL does in the filter interface so there are 3 values true, false and null which are distinct.

Comment: Thanks iant.  Yes, I found PropertyIsNull in the SLD documentation but no equivalent in the CSS documentation.  A little experimentation later and I have a working solution.  I got muddled in my testing because I originally had a much more complicated CSS style and I'd missed an explicit comma for 'or' effectively giving me an implicit 'and' between two filters.  Parring the CSS back actually hid the real issue.  My more complicated CSS, which includes several filters and scales, now works as expected.  Which is a relief because I find CSS so much easier to write and understand than SLD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out with the prompt from user30184.  Nulls are indeed ignored and must be explicitly included in the CSS or SLD filter, something I should have expected... but didn't for some reason (lack of caffeine?). So my CSS snippet becomes:

```
/* buildings */
[aeroway <> 'terminal'],[aeroway is Null]{
  fill: #aa1111;
}
```

This has been tested and works as expected.  The autogenerated SLD is also correctly formed as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aeroway</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aeroway</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>terminal</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#11aa11</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:VendorOption name="ruleEvaluation">first</sld:VendorOption>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The original code worked too, but it was just the expectation which was wrong.