# Problem with IS NULL condition in GeoServer CSS style

Tags: geoserver, null, geoserver-css-module

I have a style that divide features in PostGIS layer to four categories based on atributte *Z_KAT*. In the fourth category I want to specify that *Z_KAT* is equal to **'04'** OR **null value**.

Condition for text value '04' works well but **condition for null value doesn't work** *(only selected features with value '04')*. In SLD it works well so I can compare the result in "layer preview" but i need the style in CSS.

I also tried something like this: [Problem with NotEqualTo filters in SLD and CSS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150174/problem-with-notequalto-filters-in-sld-and-css) but without success.

How can I get this to work?

Version of GeoServer and CSS extension is 2.16.2.

Here is my code:

```
/* @title Vodní nádrž I. kategorie TBD*/
[Z_KAT='01']{
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 7;
  mark-rotation: 45;
  :mark{
    fill: #ff0000;
  }
}

/* @title Vodní nádrž II. kategorie TBD*/
[Z_KAT='02']{
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 7;
  mark-rotation: 45;
  :mark{
    fill: #008080;
  }
}

/* @title Vodní nádrž III. kategorie TBD*/
[Z_KAT='03']{
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 7;
  mark-rotation: 45;
  :mark{
    fill: #00ffff;
  }
}

/* @title Vodní nádrž IV. kategorie TBD*/
[Z_KAT='04'],[Z_KAT is Null]{
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 7;
  mark-rotation: 45;
  :mark{
    fill: #0000ff;
  }
}
```

Comment: OR queries are generally inefficient. You might try using the `coalesce` function in a single term (equivalent to `WHERE coalesce(Z_CAT,'04') = '04'`)

Comment: Good to know, but my problem is with null values, I need to define style for features that have null value in atributte Z_KAT. I also tried it with single term 'Z_KAT is Null' without OR...

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attemps I solved the problem!

I added **translation mode to flat** that translate CSS rules to SLD almost in 1:1. ([The Flat translation mode](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/cascading.html#the-flat-translation-mode))

Then I adjusted the conditions in my code to match my categories like this:

```
@mode "Flat";

/* @title Vodní nádrž I. kategorie TBD*/
[Z_KAT='01']{
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 7;
  mark-rotation: 45;
  :mark{
    fill: #ff0000;
  }
}

/* @title Vodní nádrž II. kategorie TBD*/
[Z_KAT='02']{
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 7;
  mark-rotation: 45;
  :mark{
    fill: #008080;
  }
}

/* @title Vodní nádrž III. kategorie TBD*/
[Z_KAT='03']{
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 7;
  mark-rotation: 45;
  :mark{
    fill: #00ffff;
  }
}

/* @title Vodní nádrž IV. kategorie TBD*/
[Z_KAT not in ('01','02','03')],[Z_KAT is Null]{
  mark: symbol(square);
  mark-size: 7;
  mark-rotation: 45;
  :mark{
    fill: #0000ff;
  }
}
```

Now the null values are correctly selected and the legend contains the correct categories.